# Mach-O arm64 accessing .data seciont

Tags: ios, macos, arm64, darwin, apple-silicon

now that Apple's platforms finally made a decision about architectures, I am starting to learn arm64 assembly on Darwin, and I don't find any information how to load addresses in the .data section.

On Linux, this works:

```
ldr X1, =symbol

.data
symbol:      .ascii  "foo"
```

Apple has an article why this does not work for Mach-O binaries, and [how it is done on x86](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/x86_64_code.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005044-SW1) with `@GOTPCREL`, but that does not tell me how the Clang assembler handles this on Apple Silicon.
(Putting the data into the .text section does not help, because I need it to be writable)

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: You could write it in C and see what the compiler does?

Comment: I tried that, the disassembly was half helpful. See my solution below

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985859/ios-arm64-syscalls/57092866#57092866 for some examples

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that I need to use `ADRP Rx, symbol@GOTPAGE`. Still, any more insight is appreciated