# How to call nanosleep from assembly for AArch64 (m1)

Tags: assembly, system-calls, apple-m1, arm64

I am trying to call the nanosleep syscall in assembly on the mac m1 architecture, but when I run it, I get an unexpected error. [Link](https://godbolt.org/z/6EcWYPMYfx) to the C code I try to get working in assembly. I have changed `bl nanosleep` with

```
mov x16, 0x65
svc 0x80
```

Where `0x65` is the syscall for nanosleep according to [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md#arm-32_bit_EABI)

```
mov x0, 2
str x0, [sp, 56]
str xzr, [sp, 48]
ldr x0, [sp, 56]
str x0, [sp, 24]
ldr x0, [sp, 48]
str x0, [sp, 32]
add x0, sp, 24
mov x1, 0
mov x16, 0x65
svc 0x80
```

Error

```
terminated by signal SIGSYS (Bad system call)
```

Comment: On MacOS or Linux?  The URL you linked (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md#arm-32_bit_EABI) is a table of call numbers for Linux.  Also, the specific part you linked was the 32-bit ARM table, not AArch64 aka ARM64.

Comment: Find a table for macOS.  System calls are different for each architecture and each operating system.  The best way to do the system call is to call the `nanosleep` function in the libc.  The second best way is to find a resource that applies to your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS ARM64 Syscalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985859/ios-arm64-syscalls)

Comment: I am using macOS, not iOS. Is there a system call table also there? And looking at the assembly generated from c: it uses `bl _nanosleep` instead. Is there a table also for these names?