# Call shared function from assembly ARM mac

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, arm64, mach-o

This code works but isn't what I want. I'd like to build from linux which will complain it can't find `_write`. On my mac I can compile this just fine. Notice the `bl _write` after the svc. Without it the code doesnt work (crashes on run)

```
.global _main
.align 2

_main:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    mov x29, sp

    mov X0, #1
    adr X1, hello
    mov x2, #6
;   bl  hello+0x120 ;Stubs+0x3C
;   bl _write
    bl hello+8

    mov X0, #0
    mov X16, #1
    svc 0
    bl _write
hello:
    .ascii  "Hello\n"



.extern _malloc
.extern _realloc
.extern _free
.extern _write
```

I dumped the stub and got section and wrote the below before the .extern

```
.section __TEXT,__stubs
.align 2
.p2align 12, 0x00, 4095
Stubs:
.incbin "stubs"

.section __DATA_CONST,__got
.align 3
.incbin "got"
.global _main
.align 2
```

The code seems correct, but the GOT section no longer gets replaced with valid values (it's the raw data in the got binary, in the original code it's updated with valid function pointers)

How do I get this loading correctly without depending `_write`? Or rather, what do I need to do so I can build this on linux without having libs and dylibs on the linux system? If I use the write svc I can build from linux and run on mac just fine. I'd like to use the dynamic function of malloc/free/realloc since it's more efficient than what I can do with mmap. I'm using `write` as a test

Comment: What is `bl hello+8` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @Siguza That executes the write function. The stubs section loads after hello and in this case write is the only function in the stubs table. If you run the assembly you should be able to confirm it works, as long as you don't comment out the dummy bl _write. When that's removed the GOT section no longer seems to have the jump data. I'm trying to get the dynamic linker to add it without requiring a lib so I can do it from my linux machine which is my primary dev station. My teammates don't have a mac

Comment: Do you not want to fix your dev environment so you can just use `bl _write` normally?

Comment: @Siguza I think I only seen solutions that require mac files? Are people allowed to redistribute those? I think I saw most write ups say copy it from your own mac.

Comment: It should be possible to log into the Apple Developer portal, download the "Command Line Tools for Xcode", which is a disk image, mount it, extract the .pkg file within, and use the macOS SDK in there, all on Linux. It should also be possible to build a complete representation of `.tbd` files from the macOS release binaries, as well as parts of the system headers from XNU, Libc and other Apple source releases. Fact of the matter is, you _will_ need an SDK, one way or another. You _cannot_ build valid binaries without a list of external symbols and a mapping of which libraries they come from.

Comment: @Siguza I was hoping to do something like what a coworker suggested for windows. They said I could write out the dll name then write out the list of functions and used a tool to convert that to a lib. I tried doing it with a hello world app and it worked, I was able to run on windows without using an SDK. I didn't get around to integrating that since my source only supports linux and mac. But that's what I was thinking when I wrote these questions. I'll see if I can download the disk image and read the license and if it'll allow my use case

Comment: @Siguza Apple license says it may not be installed on a non apple branded computer and may not be used across a network. Looks like I'm out of luck and should stick to public svc calls that I can build/run without the SDK

Comment: There are no "public svc calls". Apple's syscall ABI is considered a private interface, and is not stable. Syscalls get changed, replaced and removed without warning.

Comment: @Siguza oh? So far I've been using the OpenBSD syscall numbers in my assembly code and it ran just fine (on mac)

Comment: OpenBSD syscalls 7, 8, 11, 17, 18 and 19 are `getentropy`, `__tfork`, `wait4`, `obreak`, `getdtablecount` and `getrusage`. On macOS, syscalls 8, 11, 17 and 19 have been removed. Syscalls 7 and 18 are `wait4` and `getfsstat`. But either way, XNU and its syscall table is open source (mostly anyway)... you'll just have to restrict yourself to the syscalls that haven't changed across all versions you need to support, and be prepared for syscalls to get yanked out and replaced at any point.

Comment: But again, all you need in order to link are `.tbd` files. I suggest you have a look at those in the MacOS SDK - really all you need to generate them is the name of the library and a list of its symbols, which sounds very feasible to get from the arm64 macOS IPSW.

Comment: @Siguza oh really!? That sounds perfect for my use case. What tool do I use to go from list of libraries+symbols to lib/tbd/whatever I can link to? I vaguely remember the windows one was called dlltool but I can't remember how to use it