# ARM64 syscalls (differences between OSes and use of carry flag)

Tags: system-calls

I am referring to this question I asked previously about iOS ARM64 syscalls ([iOS ARM64 Syscalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985859/ios-arm64-syscalls)) where I learnt that the carry bit is used to report an error, so the value in x0 may be an error code instead of a return value.

I am curious does that apply to all OSes using ARM64 as well, such as Android, Linux, Windows etc?

Are there any resources on the differences between the various OSes' ARM64 syscalls?